# NHibernate - No persister for: System.Guid

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, orm, mapping

This problem seems a little more interesting that the usual mapping problems.

I have a method that will execute a delete with NHibernate but I am hung on some apparently simple issue. I have looked over various other similar issues that might relate to this but after a couple of hours I am hung up on it.

I have this method:

```
    public void DeleteOrganization(Guid actorId)
    {
        using (var session = _nhibernate.OpenSession())
        {
            ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction();
            try
            {
                session.Delete(actorId);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

And this HBM map:

```
    <class name="Actor, Domain.Entities" table="Actor" lazy="false">
    <id name="ActorId" column="ActorId" type="Guid" unsaved-value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
        <generator class="guid" />
    </id>
```

I still seem to get stuck here. The kicker is that it is hung on the Guid. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain your problem a bit more clearly, it's a bit hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: I get "No persister for: System.Guid" with:
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl.GetEntityPersister(String entityName)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultDeleteEventListener.OnDelete(DeleteEvent event, ISet`1 transientEntities)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultDeleteEventListener.OnDelete(DeleteEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireDelete(DeleteEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Delete(Object obj)
   at Data.Queries.OrganizationQueriesNHibernate.DeleteOrganization(Guid actorId) in c:\Data\Queries\OrganizationQueries.NHibernate.cs:line 122

Comment: It occurs on session.Delete(actorId);

Comment: Also, I did Google and my hbm.xml file is an Embedded Resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble here was that I was mapping an Organization object and trying to delete the id(not the record itself). In my previous code, I should have been trying to delete the Organization object. The correct code is as follows:

```
public void DeleteOrganization(Guid actorId)
{
    using (var session = _nhibernate.OpenSession())
    {
        ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction();
        try
        {
            var Organization = (from p in session.Query<Organization>()
                                       where p.ActorId == actorId
                                       orderby p
                                       select p).First();

            session.Delete(Organization);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```